# Разложение числа в массив

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Никак не могу придумать быстрый алгоритм разложения числа, например 600, в массив(6 элементов), каждый элемент которого не превышает значения 256. То есть в итоге на выходе у функции ложно быть 00:00:00:58:FF:FF(значения указаны в HEX). 
Если на входе число, например 123, тогда 00:00:00:00:00:7B
Помогите с алгоритмом, главное это скорость. Пишу на c#, надеюсь что сумел внятно объяснить проблему. Спасибо.

P.S. входные значения могут быть от 0 до 20000

Comment: Не очень понятно по какому принципу раскладываются числа. Почему например в первом примере первые три элемента массива равны нулю?

Comment: 0x58 + 0xFF + 0xFF = 598, где еще 2? 
И каков должен быть результат для 19999? Потому что шестью элементами Вы сможете получить максимум 1530.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, как-то так:

```
for (int idx = 0; n > 0; idx++)
{
    int next = Math.Min(n, 255);
    n -= next;
    result[idx] = next;
}
```

---

Если записывать надо с другой стороны, то подойдёт

```
for (int idx = result.Length - 1; n > 0; idx--)
```

Comment: Спасибо, ответ прямо в точку)) Перевернуть массив только осталось,но это мелочи))

Comment: @НиколаКривошеяж Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

```
    int n = 256;

    List<byte> arr = new List<byte>();

    arr.Add( (byte)(n % 255) );

    for (int i = 0; i < (n / 0xff); i++)
    {
        arr.Add(0xff);
    }
```

> не превышает значения 256

Возможно, **меньше** 256, судя по примеру?

> Не очень понятно по какому принципу раскладываются числа. Почему например в первом примере первые три элемента массива равны нулю? –  DreamChild

Присоединяюсь, тоже этот момент непонятен.

Comment: просто  числа записываются с конца массива